# client side js template engine with separate template files

Tags: javascript, template-engine, html-templates

What is the best template engine for client side?

What I look for?

1. template engine must have API to load template files from a server
2. support plain HTML(I don't want JADE or something like that)
3. written in ES5
4. is lightweight(does not require dependencies like jQuery)
5. support `if-else`, `for` or `for-in`

I already use EJS it was nice while I have not found that it works badly sometimes. I found a lot of stack trace like this

`error [Unhandled error] in [/resources/js/ejs.min.js]`

I don't want any frameworks like Angular, React, Vue, etc.

Comment: then ejs is really great for you.